# UIActionSheet Button loading a new view

Tags: iphone

I have been trying this one tonight for a while....  I have a UIActionSheet in its own controller.  I import the controller in the view I would like it to be displayed.  I can't figure out how to make a new view be shown when the user presses one of the buttons (you can see where I just send an alert right now).  Any ideas?

```
- (void)helpButtonPressedView {
    // open a dialog with two custom buttons
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                    delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Help", @"Credits", nil];
    [self parentViewController];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view]; // show from our table view (pops up in the middle of the table)
    [actionSheet release];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed: %d",buttonIndex);

    int btn = buttonIndex;

    UIAlertView *alert;

    switch (btn) {
        case 0:
            // help screen
            alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button Press Notice" message:@"The Help screen will be dispayed"
                                                           delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];   
            [alert release];

//          helpViewController = [[HelpViewController alloc] init]; 
//          [self presentModalViewController:helpViewController animated:YES];

            break;
        case 1:
            // credits screen
            alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button Press Notice" message:@"The Credits screen will be dispayed"
                                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];   
            [alert release];            
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Here is a pic of what I am trying to do...  When the user presses on the "Help" button, a new view shows.  When the user presses the "Credits" button a different view shows.  I am using IB to create the views.

## [alt text http://thecoolestcompany.com/UIActionSheet-view.jpg](http://thecoolestcompany.com/UIActionSheet-view.jpg)

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain a bit more what you are trying to do visually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a while since I asked this question -- and I figured it out a while ago....  I was missing the navigation controller to do a push of a view controller.  In other words, create the view controller then push the view using a navigation controller.  If anyone is reading this and needs sample code, post against the question and I will post the sample code...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the alert, you could create your view and add it to the current view:

```
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)];
[self.view addSubview:newView];
[newView release];
```